# How to view a large Json record in a Scala sbt REPL console?

Tags: json, scala, console, sbt

I'm testing my code which outputs a list of Json records and it looks like the console only shows the first record and part of the second record with a "..." at the end. Sometimes it cannot even show one full record if the record is very large and contains nested Json values. Is there is any way to increase the limit of the output?

I tried using `JsonHelper.print` but it looks like it is the limitation of the console.

I have multiple constraints on the code that outputs the result and I cannot simply look at the Json file by doing `grep`, etc.

Regular output:
[image: regular output]

With JsonHelper.print:
[image: with JsonHelper.print]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole json is not displayed because it's too long.

Try using a variable for the very long thing you want to display:

```
val a = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaammmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeepppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"
```

And then print it:

```
println(a)
```

the example uses a string, but It will act the same when printing a json record.